# Ruby Rescue block fails to catch Template missing code

Tags: ruby, erb

Have a small method in a Padrino helper to add partials. There are two main uses for it:

1. Have an easily configurable enable/disable system via a config file for the components.
2. Choose language specific layouts **IF** the requested layout is not found.

This is the code, I am using:

```
module SZHF
  App.helpers do

    def add_component component
      if disabled?(component)
        ""
      else
        begin
          partial(component)
        rescue
          language_specific(component)
        end
      end
    end

    def partial_exists?(component)
      File.file?(File.expand_path("../../views/#{component}.html.erb", __FILE__))
    end

    def disabled?(component)
      name = component.split("/").last
      config["enable_#{name}".to_sym] == false
    end

    def language_specific(component)
      name = component.split("/").last
      prefix = component.chomp(name)
      partial prefix + I18n.locale.to_s + "/" + name
    end

  end
end
```

But somehow the error instead being caught in the rescue block; the page returns an error stating: `undefined method`safe_concat' for nil:NilClass`.

Can't figure out why, any ideas?

Comment: To answer the title of this post the reason it is not captured is that even if it catches the first partial render attempt it will not capture the second attempt. I think this might have something to do with Padrino's and at a higher level Sinatra's in ability to determine what engine to use for rendering. Although if this were the case I would have expected it to raise an error like "Template Engine not found" are you sure your view is correct?(since safe_concat is a view helper.)

Comment: Yes, I am getting `TemplateNotFound` error when I attempt to render the unavailable template. And when I place it in the rescue block in the hopes of catching it, this error pops up.